# how to click on the elements in selenium, since items are overlapping and also they are svg element

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, selenium, firefox

how to click on the elements in selenium, since items are overlapping and also they are SVG elements.

```
<circle ng-if="$ctrl.eventVms" ng-repeat="e in $ctrl.eventVms" ng-attr-cx="{{e.x}}" ng-attr-cy="{{e.y}}" ng-attr-r="{{e.r}}" class="player-circle ng-scope" ng-style="{ fill: $ctrl.getEventTeamColour(e.event), stroke: $ctrl.getEventBorderColour(e.event) }" ng-click="$ctrl.handleTouchEvent($event, e.event)" cx="525.6" cy="131.20000000000002" r="40.001077578" style="fill: rgb(34, 70, 152); stroke: rgb(19, 147, 237);"></circle>
```

these are basically circles but they are SVG elements.
I want to click them one by one.
but the problem is somewhere they are overlapping on each other.
so, the following code is not working.

```
circle = wait2.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
            (By.XPATH, '//*[name()="svg"]//*[name()="circle" and contains(@ng-if,"$ctrl.eventVms")][1]'))))
circle.click()
```

and then I tried to click using javascript

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", circle )
```

but **the above code gives an error**

```
arguments[0].click is not a function
```

[image]

Comment: a picture of a soccer field doesn't supply us with enough information to help you

Comment: hope, I have provided enough info, if you need more, you can ask

Comment: thanks for adding the additional info and code.  I am not sure on the answer to it, but hopefully someone smarter than me will chime in and help.